# Facing issue while calculating the difference of time on different days

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a cron which runs every minute calculates the difference between current time and an entry made. This cron will stop after business hours and run again when business hour starts.

I'm having an issue only when the entry is made on the evening (6pm) of tuesday and the difference is calculated with 1am of Wednesday.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
$ticket_created_timestamp = strtotime($ticket_created_time);
$current_time = date("H:i:s");
$current_timestamp = strtotime($current_time);
$time_difference_timestamp = $current_timestamp - $ticket_created_timestamp;
```

Comment: What's your current output? What's the expected output?

Comment: this seems like an odd thing to do in the first place

Comment: @Jason My expected use case if a ticket is created at a certain time and I want to take that time and calculate it with the business hours set by the user and decide to escalate or not escalate. 

The expected output is seconds since the entry was made ie ticket created. But the moment the next day starts I start getting negative values where as the seconds should only increase.

Comment: I second that this seems like a weird thing to be doing in a cron job every minute. It doesn't sound very efficient. Is the time difference not the kind of thing you just calculate on the fly and display when a request is made? If you provide some context for what the purpose of this is, perhaps there is a better solution anyway.

Comment: @BadHorsie My user creates a ticket at any given time and I have business hours set. I need to send an escalation email when the ticket violates the SLA. Now the SLA needs to calculated with the business hours and holidays in mind.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any particular problem here but my guess is - perhaps strtotime can't correctly interpret your ticket created time value

try something like that instead

```
$ticket_created_time = "2016-08-17 12:00:00";
$objDateCreatedTicketTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ticket_created_time);

$objDateTime = new DateTime();

$time_difference_timestamp = $objDateTime->getTimestamp() - $objDateCreatedTicketTime->getTimestamp();
```

The main advantage with this method is, that you've something standardized.
You can decide how your date input looks like without loosing the flexibility of handling your dates correctly.